# Setting buttons on DocuSign's default landing pages

Tags: docusignapi

Anyone know if we can change the text appearing buttons on DocuSign's default landing pages?  We are presenting PowerForms using an iFrame and we want the text for the Home button to be more clear that it is directing them to DocuSign's homepage and not ours.

Comment: Why the down vote? Not my choice to use default landing pages I tried convincing the requestor to use our own dynamic landing page.

Comment: I'm not sure who down-voted.  Anyways, there's lots of customization available through the Preferences -> Branding page in your DS Admin Console, but if you're talking about a default landing page on the docusign.com site then I don't believe you can change that.  Still though please clarify which page in particular you are referring to...

Comment: They just made the decision to go with our own landing pages, mostly.  But in particular they were looking at the default landing pages like the Cancelled landing page [link](https://demo.docusign.net/PowerForms/LandingPages/Cancelled.htm) where it shows a Home button but it links to the Docusign homepage rather than  ours.  Since the powerform was to be presented in an iframe they thought it would be confusing that it would leave our site and go to Docusign and wanted to get the button changed to more clearly show it was directing them to Docusign's homepage.